# CPT / OPT Second Degree

Tags: usa, student-visa, study, foreign-employment, education-visa

I am about to finish my masters in healthcare (NON-STEM) and planning to go for second master's degree in IT (STEM) without using the present elective OPT period.

Can I use the OPT period of first degree after second master's degree? what would be best? Is it true that if once OPT period is used in first degree than there is no option for OPT after second degree even on STEM?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the OPT period of first degree after second master's degree?

Yes, but you must be working in the field relevant to that degree. You cannot work in IT based on the OPT granted for your healthcare degree.

> Is it true that if once OPT period is used in first degree than there is no option for OPT after second degree even on STEM?

Yes, it is true. You cannot have OPT for multiple degrees at the same level. You can have an OPT for a bachelors which then follows with an OPT for a masters, but that's not your scenario.

See examples for both scenarios on the [USCIS site here](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/optional-practical-training-extension-for-stem-students-stem-opt). See the demonstration of the 2nd masters OPT issue [on this school website](https://iso.mit.edu/knowledge-base/i-completed-a-previous-masters-degree-in-f-1-status-in-the-u-s-but-did-not-apply-for-and-have-approved-opt-based-on-that-degree-would-i-be-eligible-for-opt-during-after-completion-of-a-s/).

Comment: To clarify: The 12-month limit per degree level can be split, so you can use, for example, 9 months OPT after one Master's and 3 months OPT after another Master's. But you have to plan ahead for this to work.

Comment: That's right, they discuss that on the USCIS page I linked to. Also, CPT/OPT coordination and part-time/full-time. It's all there.